# Send an email once record is saved - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, controller, record, mailer

I'm trying to send an email to myself every time any user creates and saves a new record. I currently have this in the part of my controller that saves new records:

```
UserMailer.notification_email().deliver
```

And this in my user mailer:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def notification_email()



    mail(:to => "admin@example.co.uk",
         :subject => "Test")
  end

end
```

I'm aware it should probably pass some parameters I'm just not sure what, plus all the examples I can find send out emails to each user rather than a static email address.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't know whether I need to be passing params, and the code above doesn't currently work...

Comment: You do need to pass an argument, almost certainly, read this [guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) for more intel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set smtp settings in environment? Something like this:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  # your settings
}
```

Comment: He never said he was using ruby < 1.9

Comment: the question is tagged with ruby on rails. I think you're correct, I'd missed out the settings, just trying to find them now!

Comment: ouh, then if you haven't set the settings that is what definitely is causing the problems ;)

Comment: @sergelerator how do you know he is using some other version of ruby. He never said he was using ruby at all

Comment: If you look at the source code he posted it's clear that he is using Ruby. Your suggestion makes it clear that you also assumed he is using Ruby. I don't know what version of Ruby he is using. Changing the Hash syntax would not solve the issue if he is using Ruby >= 1.9

Comment: yes, and he never said he is using rails 3, so adopting to rails 3 wouldn't solve the issue as well. The discussion is pointless. The answer pointed to him where his problem might is, and that is what matters.